# how do you convert a string array into a integer array

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do you convert this string array `'[1, 2, 3]'` to an interger array

ok so this is not my real code but the part thats breaking

```
totalammount  = [1,2,3]

file = open("save", "w")
file.write(str(totalammount))
file = open("save", "r")
saveditems = file.read()
print(int(saveditems))
```

but if i run this it will say: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1, 2, 3]'

expected output: [1, 2, 3],
so i can take out the numbers in the array

```
saveditems[0]
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What should the output look like? can you give an example? You probably will have to iterate over `totalAmount`. Converting it to a string is hardly ever the correct thing to do (but very useful wenn debugging)

Comment: Use a proper serialization format instead of just calling `str` on the value. In this case, JSON will do the job nicely (and give identical output in this particular case).

Comment: I think your question can be boiled down to why does this error `print(float('[1,2,3]'))` ? And the answer is because you ask for the string to be converted into a single float value, which isn't possible.  You need to parse the string and convert it to a list, then convert each element in the list.  See Thomas' response for making this easy for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eval() function

```
>>> t = '[1, 2, 3]'
>>> a = eval(t)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

but, as suggested in the comments, use json format.
('save' file contains [1,2,3])

```
>>> f = open("save", "r")
>>> myvalue = json.load(f)
>>> myvalue
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```